# how to limit wildcard result to only what is typed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

**problem overview**

i'm trying to select all name beginning  with  the typed name from an input field

**my attempt**

i have a search function that is called onkeypress and the functions gets the typed text from the html form and send it to a php page from process.

**my problem**

the query returns only results that contain the typed text in it's completeness, which is actually what i want, after which the result get distorted my adding text which contain some part of the search text and that i don't want

**program code**

html form

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="search(this.value)"/>
 <div id="search">
</div>
```

function called on key press

```
 function search(val)
     {




            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"lsearch.php",
                data:{
                        co:val,
                        co2:pgmid
                },
            success:function(data){
                //alert("complete");
                $("#search").html(data);
                },

            });
    }
```

php process page

```
$coname=$_POST['cof'];
$coun="select * from registration where full_name LIKE '$coname%'";
                                       $rcount2=mysqli_query($cons,$coun);
```

have also uploaded a screenshot of both the abnormal and expected result.

What i get:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Use wildcard operators in your search string; `%`. ***However*** you ***need*** to change your logic as you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. Research parameterised queries.

Comment: Can you please explain properly. what is the response that you are getting and what response are you looking for exactly.

Comment: i actually used the % operator at the beginning but i forget to show it.the complete code is like this  $coun="select * from registration where full_name LIKE '%$coname%'

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Your query "$coun="select * from registration where full_name LIKE '$coname%' " will return values where the value starts with $coname.

Comment: it also fetches  full_name that contain any word similar to $coname, for example if i search for abed it returns abel, elizabeth because they contain abe

Comment: `LIKE '%$coname%'` = find anywhere, `LIKE '$coname%'` = find at the start  (note the `%` is missing from the start to force it to match the start)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the PHP process page. Using a % on both sides of your LIKE will return values that include what was entered anywhere in the name instead of just at the beginning. Change:

```
$coname=$_POST['cof'];
$coun="select * from registration where full_name LIKE '%$coname%'
```

to:

```
$coname=$_POST['cof'];
$coun="select * from registration where full_name LIKE '$coname%'
```

and you should get the results you are looking for.

Comment: the result came out normal but after some seconds the whole things got distorted again

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make any sense at all. As something starts to get typed in the search field data will be returned and as they continue to type more results will be returned narrowing down their choices. Is the success branch of your Ajax call replacing the results shown as new data comes back from the Ajax query?

Comment: yes, the ajax calls replaces the result shown in a div

Comment: Show us that code please (update your original post). From your description that is not actually happening.

Comment: In your success function try `document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = data;`

Comment: at first the result displays normal after which it get distorted as if the query is re-running itself

Comment: Then you need to go back and check your setup for Ajax and what might be causing the search to be called after the user has stopped typing.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

To match all Jonh, Johan, jojo, jorgio etc use:

```
  select * from registration where full_name REGEX '^jo.*'
```

Comment: The example should work on Mysql 5.7+ What DB/version are you using?

Comment: mysql version is 5.6.26